# Missed optimization based on using a reference to a counter variable

Tags: rust, io

In the following example I'm reading a 2.7GiB file from my desktop, count the bytes and do something with the bytes that prevents optimizing the loop away.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::{BufReader, ErrorKind};

fn main() {
    let file = File::open("/home/seb/Desktop/ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso")
        .expect("Cannot read file.");

    let buf = BufReader::new(file);

    let mut x = 0u8;

    let mut num_bytes = 0usize;

    read(buf, &mut num_bytes, &mut x);
    print(num_bytes, x);
}

fn read(mut buf: BufReader<File>, num_bytes: &mut usize, x: &mut u8) {
    let mut bytes = [0; 512];
    loop {
        match buf.read(&mut bytes) {
            Ok(0) => break,
            Ok(n) => {
                for i in 0..n {
                    *num_bytes += n;
                    *x += bytes[i];
                }
            }
            Err(ref e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::Interrupted => continue,
            Err(e) => panic!("{:?}", e),
        };
    }
}

fn print(num_bytes: usize, x: u8) {
    println!("{}", num_bytes);
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

I get roughly 20% differences in throughput based on whether `num_bytes` is passed as a reference to `print` or by value. Unscientifically testing through `time` shows consistent differences, always in the same ballpark.

```
fn print(num_bytes: &usize, x: u8) {
    println!("{}", num_bytes);
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

```sh
# passing num_bytes by value
cargo build --release && time target/release/test_read
   Compiling test_read v0.1.0 (/data/rust_projects/test_read)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.23s
2785017856
101
target/release/test_read  0,67s user 0,29s system 99% cpu 0,966 total
```

As soon as a reference to `num_bytes` is used later, the program is about 20% slower.

```
fn print(num_bytes: usize, x: u8) {
    println!("{}", num_bytes);
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

```sh
# passing num_bytes by reference
cargo build --release && time target/release/test_read
   Compiling test_read v0.1.0 (/data/rust_projects/test_read)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.22s
2785017856
101
target/release/test_read  1,00s user 0,26s system 99% cpu 1,258 total
```

I'm running this on Ubuntu 20.04 and with Rust 1.50.

The example is mostly taken from this question: [What is a faster way to iterate through the bytes of a file in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66645551/what-is-a-faster-way-to-iterate-through-the-bytes-of-a-file-in-rust/66646035)

**Is there any explanation for using a reference to a counter variable to cause this?**

Comment: You did one run that lasted one second. The difference here is not statistically sound. Try 100 runs or more, and randomly switch between the two versions to be sure it's not some caching thing or a CPU "turbo" boost that tops out.

Comment: I have tried this probably 10 to 20 times by now, the difference goes away as soon as I remove printing the mutable `num_bytes`

Comment: I think you're getting random noise. The name of a variable shouldn't have an effect. If you call it `a` or `b` or `c` do you get totally different results for each? Are they consistently different? Does the executable you build *differ in any way at all*? It shouldn't.

Comment: The naming doesn't matter, what does seem to matter is not printing the `num_bytes` assigned before the loop. I doubt it's random noise as I've been running this over and over again and the numbers stay within ~50 MiB/s for each of the variants, with a stable distance of about ~500 MiB/s.

Comment: Both versions you've shown here in the output print. Am I missing something? Do you need to print? If not, skip it.

Comment: `I'm seeing massive differences in throughput based on shadowing num_bytes when converting Bytes to MiB.` was the only thing I could figure out while posting this question. I've now narrowed it down to printing the `num_bytes` as declared before the loop causing the slowdown. I'm not using this in any code, I was just very confused by the differences and am actually still confused as to why this is apparently influencing the speed of the loop.

Comment: Look at the dumped assembly output and find out more.

Answer (score 1):

After narrowing down the example, it turns out that using the reference to the counter variable stops the compiler from optimizing away additions on every loop iteration. `by_ref` and `by_value` two benches here have a ten-fold difference in run time, while `by_ref_use_length` matches `by_value`:

```
// benches/bench.rs
pub fn by_ref(buf: &[u8]) {
    let mut x = 0u8;
    let mut num_bytes = 0usize;

    for &byte in buf {
        num_bytes += 1;
        x += byte;
    }
    black_box((&num_bytes, x));
}

pub fn by_value(buf: &[u8]) {
    let mut x = 0u8;
    let mut num_bytes = 0usize;

    for &byte in buf {
        num_bytes += 1;
        x += byte;
    }
    black_box((num_bytes, x));
}

pub fn by_ref_use_length(buf: &[u8]) {
    let mut x = 0u8;
    let num_bytes = buf.len();

    for &byte in buf {
        x += byte;
    }
    black_box((&num_bytes, x));
}


fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let buf = vec![0; 1024 * 1024 * 64];
    c.bench_function("len num_bytes by ref", |b| b.iter(|| by_ref_use_length(&buf)));
    c.bench_function("num_bytes by ref", |b| b.iter(|| by_ref(&buf)));
    c.bench_function("num_bytes by value", |b| b.iter(|| by_value(&buf)));
}

criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

```
# Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "test_read"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [""]
edition = "2018"

[dev-dependencies]
criterion = "0.3"

[[bench]]
name = "bench"
harness = false
```

```sh
cargo bench --all
num_bytes by ref        time:   [723.42 us 726.62 us 729.54 us]                             
Found 4 outliers among 100 measurements (4.00%)
  4 (4.00%) low mild

len num_bytes by ref    time:   [696.26 us 699.16 us 701.87 us]                                 
Found 4 outliers among 100 measurements (4.00%)
  4 (4.00%) low mild


num_bytes by value      time:   [721.68 us 725.48 us 729.55 us]                               
Found 2 outliers among 100 measurements (2.00%)
  2 (2.00%) low mild
```

https://rust.godbolt.org/z/zqfn7n shows no instructions related to the counter in the loop when the counter variable is not passed by reference, whereas passing by reference prevents such optimizations. I'm not familiar with reading assembly, but I'm assuming that the length of the input slice is used rather than actually incrementing.

In the original example, the differences were only about 20%, which is probably due to the dependency on IO which restricts the optimization to adding `n` on every `read` iteration rather than simply returning the length of the input array. In fact, changing the counter in the loop to a single addition outside the inner loop matches the performance of both implementations:

```
    let mut bytes = [0; 512];
    loop {
        match buf.read(&mut bytes) {
            Ok(0) => break,
            Ok(n) => {
                // pulling the num_bytes addition out of the inner loop
                // seems to imitate the optimization done by the compiler
                // when num_bytes is not passed anywhere by reference.
                num_bytes += n;
                for i in 0..n {
                    x += bytes[i];
                }
            },
            Err(ref e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::Interrupted => continue,
            Err(e) => panic!("{:?}", e),
        };
    }
```

This should answer *what* happens, but I have no clue *why* the optimization depends on a reference being used somewhere downstream.